# Why does copy_if not work correctly with STL vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Spent an ocean of time and read a bunch of pages on SO - but it didn't help. My problem is as follows. In my Win32 C++ application I use the namespace:

```
using namespace std;
```

And there are three vectors:

```
std :: vector <wstring> A;
std :: vector <wstring> B;
std :: vector <wstring> С;
```

Vector A contains some set of elements, vector B contains a subset of elements from vector A, and vector C is empty - it does not contain elements. I need to fill vector C with those elements from vector A that are not in vector B. For this I do:

```
std::copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(C),
                    [](const std::wstring & arg)
                    { return (std::find(B.begin(), B.end(), arg) == 
B.end()); });
```

But as a result, all elements are copied from vector A to vector C. Why? What am I doing wrong? Could this be hindered by the fact that I also use headers:

```
#include <boost / interprocess / containers / vector.hpp>
#include <boost / interprocess / containers / string.hpp>
```

or not?
Your help will be highly appreciated by me.

Below the contents of vector: "filePath" means "A" and "pathsToUntransmittedFiles" means "C":

[image]

Below is text representation of input:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.sfx
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zCon.sfx
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.chm
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip.dll
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7-zip32.dll
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\descript.ion
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\History.txt
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\License.txt
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\readme.txt
```

Comment: Since you are using `std::vector` (`vector` inside `std` namespace), I think there shouldn't be conflict with boost containers (since boost has its own namespace).

Comment: Also, can you post a sample input?

Comment: @kiner_shah, By example input, do you mean the result of filling vector C?

Comment: If your vectors are sorted you can also use [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) which does exactly what you want, but doesn't have O(n²) complexity like yours.

Comment: @Possseidon I've tried but result is the same, set_difference doesn't work either.

Comment: You posted A and C, but which ones should be excluded because they are in B?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @Prohor *Spent an ocean of time and read a bunch of pages on SO* -- Why not put together a simple 5 or 6 line `main` program, and then experiment with that program?  That's the first thing any programmer who is testing simple things like this out would have done.

Comment: @Prohor [Take this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9c15ad1286e5926).  It uses both your approach and `set_difference`.  You see the output for both.   Change the program at the link to duplicate the error(s) that you're seeing.  It is a program just like that you should have created, so as to ensure there isn't something compiler or compiler-library related (and it probably isn't anyway).

Comment: @Prohor, can you please update the question with the compiler information - compiler version, platform (x86, x64), etc.?

Comment: @kiner_shah, Visual Studio 2019, application configuration - x86, OS - Windows 10

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I take your code std::sort(A.begin(), A.end()); std::sort(B.begin(), .end());
std::set_difference(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(C)); but I stil have the same result

Comment: @Prohor Did you take the code at the link, made *no changes* to it. compiled, and ran the  code?  If you're inserting that code into your (broken) program, that is not what you should have done.  Take the code as-is, compile it, run it.  You see it works correctly.  Now take *that code*, make changes to it, and duplicate the error you're claiming happens.  Once you do that, *then* post that code here.  I took the code at the link, and ran it in Visual Studio 2019 -- there were no issues.  Since you still haven't posted a [mcve], start with that code at the link.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes, your application works correctly

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I could not reproduce, so I will look for flaws in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the lambda function by capturing references like `[&](args..) { ... }`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> A{L"abcd", L"bcd", L"sss"};
    std::vector<std::wstring> B{L"sss", L"asd", L"bcd"};
    std::vector<std::wstring> C;

    std::copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(C),
                        [&](const std::wstring & arg)
                        { return (std::find(B.begin(), B.end(), arg) == 
    B.end()); });

    for (std::wstring s : C) {
        std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this can be the problem, I'm guessing the vectors are global variables and don't therefore require capturing, otherwise the code wouldn't compile at all

Comment: @AlanBirtles, for some reason, I tried to run the code in the question on godbolt.org and it threw compilation errors. https://godbolt.org/z/5bqs6M8zc

Comment: std::vector<std::wstring> excluded_values; for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) excluded_values.push_back(A[i]); std::copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(C),[&excluded_values](const std::wstring& arg)  { return (std::find(excluded_values.begin(), excluded_values.end(), arg) == excluded_values.end()); }); it did not help

Comment: @Prohor, does it still fill C with the whole array A?

Comment: @kiner_shah, unfortunately - yes

Comment: @Prohor, please update the post with the sample inputs which you are using for `A`, `B` and `C`, along with the output/errors you get. Please don't post it as image but rather copy/paste the text.

Comment: @kiner_shah this morning, I made some corrections in my code and now it works without errors, but vector A into vector B continues to be copied completely

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with your code when add [**&**]. It's content of the vectors and comparison who cause the promblem. May be something to do with escape characters `\`.

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> A{ 
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.dll"         ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"         ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.sfx"         ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zCon.sfx"      ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zFM.exe"       ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe"        ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7-zip.chm"      ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7-zip.dll"      ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7-zip32.dll"    ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\descript.ion"   ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\History.txt"    ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\License.txt"    ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\readme.txt"
    };
    std::vector<std::wstring> B{ 
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zCon.sfx"      ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zFM.exe"       ,
        L"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe"        
    
    };
    std::vector<std::wstring> C;

    std::copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(C),
        [&B](const std::wstring& arg)
        { return (std::find(B.begin(), B.end(), arg) ==
            B.end()); });


    for (std::wstring s : C) {
        std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I failed again. The reason is probably that something is wrong in the application source code. All three vectors are declared globally with the file scope, and the assignment from A to C is performed inside the PPL task, which is started from the event of the window procedure WndProc (), although the filling of vectors A and B also occurs in the PPL task, but only another, which also triggered from an event in WinProc (), albeit from a different one.

Comment: Many thanks to you all, guys, I will look for the reason myself, apparently it won't work otherwise.